# CSS-grid not responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 3layred with animation in between. The backdrop is the full image, in between is the animations and the outer-layer has transparent places where snow and fire is supposed to show

I cant get the grid to keep staying responsive when I change screensize

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Interactive Christmas Card</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .grid-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 80vh;
    }

    #rear_image_wrapper {
      background: url('assets/images/rear_image.png') no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 80vh;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    #between-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    #front_image_wrapper {
      background: url('assets/images/front_image.png') no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 80vh;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .top-row, .bottom-row {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-auto-rows: minmax(10vh, auto);
    }

    .top3col, .bottom2col {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    .top3col1row {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    div {
      border: 0.5px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .top1col, .top2col, .top3col1row1col, .top3col1row2col, .bottom1col, .bottom2col1row, .bottom2col2row, .bottom3col {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="card_gen.html">Card Generator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="dennis.html">Daniel</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="ruksana.html">Ruksana</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="ekaterina.html">Ekaterina</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="atchuchi.html">Atchutchi</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div id="rear_image_wrapper"></div>
    <div id="between-wrapper">
      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="top1col">top1col</div>
        <div class="top2col">top2col</div>
        <div class="top3col">
          <div class="top3col1row">
            <div class="top3col1row1col">top3col1row1col</div>
            <div class="top3col1row2col">top3col1row2col</div>
          </div>
          <div class="top3col2row">top3col2row</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-row">
        <div class="bottom1col">bottom1col</div>
        <div class="bottom2col">
          <div class="bottom2col1row">bottom2col1row</div>
          <div class="bottom2col2row">bottom2col2row</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom3col">bottom3col</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="front_image_wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Goal is that all 3 layers should follow each other in size. Back-image, between-layer and front-layer

Comment: Not sure it's a simple issue. Inline images scale differently than background images but a [mcve] would be ideal here.